# How to find all $f \in V$ such that $(\int_0^{\ln3}e^x f(x) dx)^2 \leq 2 \int_0^{\\ln 3} e^x [f(x)]^2 dx $

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

How to find all $f \in V$ such that $(\int_0^{\ln3}e^x f(x) dx)^2 \leq 2 \int_0^{\\ln 3} e^x [f(x)]^2 dx  $

$V$ is a inner product space where $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^{\ln3}e^x f(x) g(x)dx$

I know this is a Cauchy-schwarz inequality and I'm able to prove it, but how to find f?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All $f\in V$ will satisfy this inequality. It is known as [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). Note that
$$
\frac12\int_0^{\log(3)}e^x\,\mathrm{d}x=1\tag{1}
$$
Thus, Jensen says that
$$
\left(\frac12\int_0^{\log(3)}f(x)\,e^x\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\le\frac12\int_0^{\log(3)}f(x)^2e^x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
$$
which is $\frac14$ of the inequality in question.

Since $e^{x/2}$ is bounded above and below on $[0,\log(3)]$, every function in $L^2[0,\log(3)]$ is also in $V$.

Comment: If $\leq$ in the original question is changed to $=$ does this answer still hold?

Comment: @xiamx: If your question was supposed to be "for which $f$ does equality hold?" then that is different. Then you need to look at
$$
\frac12\int_0^{\log(3)}\left(f(x)-\langle f,f\rangle^{1/2}\right)^2e^x\,\mathrm{d}x =\int_0^{\log(3)}f(x)^2\,e^x\,\mathrm{d}x-\langle f,f\rangle^{1/2}\int_0^{\log(3)}f(x)\,e^x\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
to see that equality can only happen when $f$ is constant.